# Fluctuating RAM in google colab while running a BERT model

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, ram, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am running a simple comment classification task on google colab. I am using DistilBERT for contextual embeddings.I use only 4000 training sample cause the notebook keeps on crashing.
When I run the cell for obtaining the embeddings, I keep a tab on how the RAM utilisation increases. I am seeing that it oscillates from somewhere between 3gb to 8gb.
Should not it be just increasing? Can anyone explain how this works at lower level.

Here is my code, the cell block at last is where I am seeing the above said thing.

```py
# For DistilBERT:
model_class, tokenizer_class, pretrained_weights = (ppb.DistilBertModel, ppb.DistilBertTokenizer, 'distilbert-base-uncased')

## Want BERT instead of distilBERT? Uncomment the following line:
#model_class, tokenizer_class, pretrained_weights = (ppb.BertModel, ppb.BertTokenizer, 'bert-base-uncased')

# Load pretrained model/tokenizer
tokenizer = tokenizer_class.from_pretrained(pretrained_weights)
model = model_class.from_pretrained(pretrained_weights)

max_len=80
tokenized = sample['comment_text'].apply((lambda x: tokenizer.encode(x, add_special_tokens=True,max_length= max_len)))

padded = np.array([i + [0]*(max_len-len(i)) for i in tokenized.values])

attention_mask = np.where(padded != 0, 1, 0)
attention_mask.shape

input_ids = torch.tensor(padded)  
attention_mask = torch.tensor(attention_mask)

**with torch.no_grad():
    last_hidden_states = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)**
```