# DistilBERT, less than 512 tokens, Colab crash

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, google-colaboratory, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I'm following this guide https://jalammar.github.io/a-visual-guide-to-using-bert-for-the-first-time/ and my text observations contain less than 250-300 words on average, so I don't  have 512 tokens in any text row.

But similar to this question: [Fluctuating RAM in google colab while running a BERT model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64520322/fluctuating-ram-in-google-colab-while-running-a-bert-model) I have to limit `max_length` to less than 100, because otherwise Google Colab crashes.

I see other examples of applying BERT-based transformers and using Pytorch `DataLoader` to load data in batches but can't figure out how to implement it in this example.

Answer (score 1):

As you said correctly it seems like in the tutorial you show there is no batching used, so the entire data is handed to the model in one batch which might be too much for the ressources colab allows you to use.

If you just want to get it to work you can try to limit the number of rows in the data it similarily to how this tutorial did it (in this case 2000):
https://www.kaggle.com/rahulvks/distilbert-text-classification

Or, even better, use dataloaders and then iterate over them similarily to how this tutorial does it: https://seekinginference.com/applied_nlp/distilbert.html

Generally when working with transformer models in Colab you should make sure to activate GPU usage (Edit -> Notebook Settings) since this gives you access to some pretty nice GPUs for free and drastically improves training speed.